# Async call in node.js vs. mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a node.js app that uses mongoose to connect to 
a mongodb; i need to select all the documents inserted and i
i've problems with async stuff.

I've made a model with the following function:

```
exports.listItems=function() {
    Ticket.find({}, function(err,tkts) {
            console.log(tkts);
            return tkts;
    });
}
```

I correctly see the value of "tkts", but when i call it from:

```
exports.list = function(req,res) {
    var items=db.listItems();
    console.log("Items:"+items);
    res.render('list', { title: title, items:items });
}
```

defined in app.js as:

```
app.get('/list', routes.list);
```

items is undefined (i think because of non-async definition of db.list()).

What am i doing wrong and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use callbacks more appropriately.

A more traditional `listItems` function would be

```
exports.listItems = function(done) {
    Ticket.find({}, done);
}
```

Then, in `list`, you could do:

```
exports.list = function(req,res) {
    db.listItems(function(err,items){
        console.log("Items:"+items);
        res.render('list', { title: title, items:items });
    });
}
```

Because of the **asynchronous** nature of Node.JS, you should always pass (and expect) a callback in your functions. So that you can defer execution if something asynchronous is executed.

Also: be sure to check out [**async**](https://github.com/caolan/async), its an insanely good and easy-to-use library, that will simplify complex async scenarios in a breeze.