# How to redirect to another page in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express, ejs

I have a login and a signup page. When random user wants to login, and login is successful, I want to redirect him to another .ejs page (for example UserHomePage.ejs), however, nothing I've tried have worked so far.

```
if (loggedIn)
    {
        console.log("Success!");
        res.redirect('/UserHomePage');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Error!");
    }
```

I would also like to know, how to redirect a user on button click.

Let's say I'm on display user page, where I display all of my users, then there is "add another used button". How do i do that? How do I redirect user to Register.js page after onclick?

```
<h2>List of users</h2>
<ul>
<% uporabniki.forEach(function(user) { %>
<li>  
  <%= user.attributes.name %>
  <%= user.attributes.last name %>
</li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
<h3>Add another user</h3>
<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Add user" />
</form>
```

Comment: "how to redirect on button click" -- isn't that just location.href = '/url/to/visit' in the onclick?

Comment: @RobBrander you mean like onclick="location.href='localhost:3000/Registration'" or onclick="location.href='/Registration'" or anything else?

Comment: yeah, <button type="button" onclick="location.href='/Registration' ">Registration</button>

Comment: thank you, that works fine! @RobBrander

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should return the line that redirects

```
return res.redirect('/UserHomePage');
```

Comment: And how do we redirect to a nodeJS page and trigger a function with request parameters  (i.e. body) with it ?

Comment: Same question @Techdive.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I'll try to help you using one my examples. First of all, you need to know I am using **express** for my application directory structure and for creating files like **app.js** in an automatically way. My **login.html** looks like:

```
...
<div class="form">
<h2>Login information</h2>
<form action="/login" method = "post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="email" required/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

The important thing here is **action="/login"**. This is the path I use in my **index.js** (for navigating between the views) which look like this:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect : '/home', 
    failureRedirect : '/login', 
    failureFlash : true
}));

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
        response.render('pages/home');
});
```

This allows me to redirect to another page after a succesful login. There is a helpful tutorial you could check out for redirecting between pages:

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/

To read a statement like **<%= user.attributes.name %>** let's have a look at a simple **profile.html** which has the following structure:

```
<div id = "profile">
<h3>Profilinformationen</h3>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label id = "usernameLabel">Username:</label>
            <input type = "text" id="usernameText" value = "<%= user.user.username %>" />
            <br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

To get the the attributes of the **user** variable, you have to initialize a **user** variable in your routing.js (called index.js in my case). This looks like

```
app.get('/profile', auth, function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/profile', {
        user : request.user
    });
});
```

I am using mongoose for my object model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var role     = require('./role');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user             : {
        username     : String,
        email        : String,
        password     : String
    }
});
```

Ask me anytime for further questions...
Best regards,
Nazar

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful. Altho i cannot mark your answer as the "right one" since i already did this :(

Comment: and yeh maybe another question with combining tables.  how can i read the <%= user.attributes.name %> and put it in my .js file. For example. I have a list of items, i choose one, and then i add it to some user, meaning i need to get items id and name...

Comment: thanks for the info, can you suggest something on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445746/get-selected-value-from-drop-down-and-use-it-in-router-get-nodejs

Answer (score 5):

In another way you can use `window.location.href="your URL"`

e.g.:

```
res.send('<script>window.location.href="your URL";</script>');
```

or:

```
return res.redirect("your url");
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user successful login into your Node app, I'm thinking that you are using Express, isn't ? Well you can redirect easy by using `res.redirect`. Like:

```
app.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
  // Your logic and then redirect
  res.redirect('/user_profile');
});
```

Comment: isn't what i wrote exactly the same, but isn't working?

Comment: Are you using Express, because if you are using pure Node http the redirect is different.

Comment: yeh im using express

Answer (score 1):

The If else statement needs to be wrapped in a .get or a .post to redirect.  Such as

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
});
```

or

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nazar Medeiros - Your solution uses passport with Express. I am not using passport, just express-jwt. I might be doing something wrong, but when a user logs in, the token needs to return to the client side. From what I have found so far, this means we have to return a json with the token and therefor cannot call redirect.  Is there something I am missing there?

To get around this, I simply return the token, store it in my cookies and then make a ajax GET request (with the valid token). When that ajax call returns I replace the body's html with the returned HTML.  This is probably not the right way to do it, but I can't find a better way.  Here is my JQuery JavaScript code.

```
function loginUser(){
  $.post("/users/login", {
    username: $( '#login_input_username' ).val(),
   password: $( '#login_input_password' ).val()
 }).done(function(res){
    document.cookie = "token = " + res.token;
    redirectToHome();
  })
}

function redirectToHome(){
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "/home",
    "type": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "authorization": "Bearer " + getCookie('token'),
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    $('body').replaceWith(response);
  });
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```