# How to redirect another page after successfully login nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'am trying to sending client to next page when login process is successful done,page is confirm page.but i am geting some error.
[image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb8Xm.png)

```
router.post('/sign_in', urlend, function(req, res) {
  var email = req.body.user_id;
  var password = req.body.password;
  if (email != '' && password != '') {
    user_modell.findOne({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        //res.status(500).send();
        console.log('error');
      } else if (!data) {
        console.log('Incorrect User ID or Password');
        return res.end();
      } else {
        res.render("confirm");
      }
    });
  }
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: return res.redirect('/HomePage');

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434978/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-node-js

Comment: sir i have already do this, please refer the screennshot attached in question. i am facing unhanded error events,while i am use of res parameeter.

Comment: why i getting such type of error every time while i am using res object to redirect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.redirect('URL');` is used to redirect request to another page

**Code**

```
router.post('/sign_in',urlend,function(req,res){
    var email=req.body.user_id;
    var password=req.body.password;
    if(email!='' && password!=''){      
        user_modell.findOne({email:email,password:password},function(err,data){
            if(err){
                //res.status(500).send();
                console.log('error');
            } else if(!data){
                console.log('Incorrect User ID or Password');
                return res.end();
            }else{
                  res.redirect("/confirm"); 
            }
        });
    }
    res.end();
});
```

You can use [express-redirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-redirect) package as well.

**Explanation for your error**

The error `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` is because your code tries to send two responses. `model.findOne` is like a timeout. You pass in a callback and it executes later. This means that `res.end()` sets the headers and sends a response. Then later, your callback is called and you try to send another response.

Think of it like a telephone conversation: someone calls you and tells you their email/password, you say "Hold on a second, I'll just check", then you hang up the phone and pick up a notebook of known emails/passwords. Then when you figure out what you want to respond with, you pick the phone back up, but there's nobody listening, cause you cut them off when you hung up the phone!

Comment: sir i trying with your code but i am still in error.please refer the screennshot attached in question. i am facing unhanded error.