# Hosting 2 website on a single URL in Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I have 2 websites compiled using angular-universal (For SEO). I need to host both these websites on a single url. Based on url change it will be directed to the relevant website

Project structure

```
dist
  - repair    
      -browser    
      -server    
      -server.js
  - renew
    - browser
    - server
    - server.js
```

I am new to this environment and this is the code i tried but the port is clashing and even changing the port is not working. Any help will be appreciated

```
    app.get('/repair', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
        const server = require('./dist/repair/server.js');
        server.app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on: http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        let err = new def.NError(500, messages.errInternalServerError, error.message);
        next(err);
    }
    console.log("repair");
});

app.get('/renew', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
        const server = require('./dist/renew/server.js');
        server.app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on: http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        let err = new def.NError(500, messages.errInternalServerError, error.message);
        next(err);
    }
    console.log("renew");
});


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    console.log('server running', ' at port: ', 8080);
});
```

Comment: You could run each on a different port (private) and then have a 3rd one, on public port which would transfer the request to the correct nodejs instance based on the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for your case is to use nginx (web server) proxy instead of nodejs redirection.

SOLUTION 1 : So below is the solution for proxying using nginx.

```
    #worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
   sendfile on;

   gzip on;
   gzip_disable "msie6";

   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_comp_level 6;
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    upstream api_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:8042;
    }

    upstream admin_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:8043;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 404;
    }

   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
           proxy_pass         http://api_server;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }


        location /proj-admin {
           proxy_pass         http://admin_server;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

    }
}
```

Replace the nginx.conf with the above config.

SOLUTION 2 : still if you want to proxy using nodejs

[How to redirect to another page in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434978/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-node-js/48307204)

Comment: You forgot to mention running each app with those ports listed

Comment: Is this two is same build ?

Comment: I don't know, but OP is trying to make them into one

Comment: If you could build 2 apps in two ports by changing ports in your server.ts file in your angular universal then it would be better. Just proxy using webserver, i always suggest you to do that since when you scale your application this is the best way to do.

Comment: I agree, I'm just saying you picked 8042 and 8043 randomly? But haven't mentioned how/where those numbers need to be placed for each app to work with them