# How to redirect to another page when click on hyperlink href using node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

**server.js:**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-Type':'text/html'});
    fs.readFile('./index.html',null,function(error,data){
        if(error) 
        {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found');
        }
        else
        {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
    fs.readFile('./about.html',null,function(error,data){
        if(error) 
        {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found');
        }
        else
        {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
```

I am new in Node.js where I have created a simple HTML page i.e. `index.html` and `about.html` inside the folder. I had also created a `server.js`.

Now, when I run a command on `cmd` and run on `localhost:8080` then index.html page are showing but when I click on hyperlink i.e. `<a href="about.html"></a>` then it not working.

So, How can I create a hyperlink in node js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another page in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434978/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-node-js)

Comment: What code have you used to attempt the redirect? See an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render different html files you have to use url-based redirect. I have used your example to make it more clear.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="./about.html">go to about</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**about.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="./index.html"> go to index</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-Type':'text/html'});
    if(request.url=='/' || request.url=='/index.html'){
        fs.readFile('./index.html',null,function(error,data){
            if(error) 
            {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('File not found');
            }
            else
            {
                response.write(data);
            }
            response.end();
        });
    }
    if(request.url=='/about.html'){
        fs.readFile('./about.html',null,function(error,data){
            if(error) 
            {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('File not found');
            }
            else
            {
                response.write(data);
            }
            response.end();
        });
    }
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

To serve static files in express you need to configure the middleware with express.static, like this:

```
app.use('/', express.static('html'));
```

This way, if you have all your html files inside the html folder, express will map the / to where your html files are.

Just remembering, the path '/' is relative from where you start your node process.